# Calling Admob ads inside recyclerview item requests 40 times more than impressions. Am I requesting ads the right way?

Tags: android-recyclerview, admob

I am calling AdRequest.Builder().build() once in onCreateViewHolder and again inside RecyclerView.Viewholder.

195 requests (100% matched, still showing only 5 impressions). I have seen many question where the the impressions are between 40-60% of the requests, and they say it is normal. In my case only 2.5% of the requests turn into impressions.

Is this the right way to call adRequests? What am I doing wrong?

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder> {

public NewsAdapter(Context mContext, List<News> newsList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.newsList = newsList;
}

@Override
public NewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news, null);
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    view.setLayoutParams(lp);

    NewsViewHolder holder = new NewsViewHolder(view);
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(mContext);

    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    Base.initialize(mContext);
    return holder;
}


class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView headlineView, sourceView, sectionView, timeView, descriptionView;
    ImageView imageView, shareView;
    LinearLayout newsLayout, innerLinearLayout;



    public NewsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        headlineView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.headlines_textview);
        sourceView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_source_textview);
        timeView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_textview);
        descriptionView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description_textview);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_imageView);
        newsLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_news);
        innerLinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.headline_details_linearlayout);
        shareView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.share_imageview);



        descriptionView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                clicked++;
                if (clicked % 3 == 0) {
                    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                    } 

                }
                mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdClosed() {
                        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}